# How to disable Autoplay events for a specific device?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, microphone, autoplay

I have [this](http://www.bluemic.com/yeti/) USB microphone, and I usually keep it connected to my Windows XP box for recording, but since there are not too many USB ports on it, I sometimes have to disconnect it to use the port for another device. The problem is, everytime it is reconnected it sets itself as the default sound output device.

It is quite annoying that I have to configure the computer's sound devices everytime I plug in the mic, so I was wondering if there is any way to disable Autoplay in Windows XP for a certain device (not all of them, because I use Autoplay on some of my other USB devices).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 Explorer AutoPlay notifications - how to disable for certain devices?](http://superuser.com/questions/267441/windows-7-explorer-autoplay-notifications-how-to-disable-for-certain-devices)

Comment: @techie007 I don't care about the notifications, it's the background process that I want to stop

Comment: I think what you're running into isn't related to AutoPlay;  Perhaps try disabling AutoPlay completely, see if that stops the effect you are seeing. If not, you know it's not probably not AutoPlay, and that you may need to approach it from another direction. It's definitely odd a microphone would become the default output device.

Comment: @techie007 I completely disabled autoplay, and it doesn't do that anymore

Comment: And it starts doing it again once you (re)enable AutoPlay?

Comment: @techie007 yes.